# MaterializeCSS tabs - Not displaying more than 4 tabs

Tags: javascript, materialize

I have been trying to work with the Javascript tabs provided by Materialize CSS. For some reason my browser will only display the first 4 tabs. I then discovered that if I reduce the width of my browser, the extra tabs (tab 5, tab 6 etc) will then also become visible. This is the case in both Safari and FireFox. I think it's a very strange problem and was wondering in anyone here can explain why this happens. Below is the code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Tabs -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <ul class="tabs">
          <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test1">Tab 1</a></li>
          <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test2">Tab 2</a></li>
          <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test3">Tab 3</a></li>
          <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Tab 4</a></li>
          <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test5">Tab 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
      <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
      <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
      <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
      <div id="test5" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Init Tabs -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('ul.tabs').tabs();
          });
        </script>


    <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

From MaterializeCSS:
http://materializecss.com/tabs.html

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think it is due to gird system used in Materialize Css. class="col
>   s3" use 25% width in big devices. You have more then five li with
>   class="col s3" in ul. Cross 100% width.The fifth tab is move in next
>   row it is not visible because height of tabs class in ul is small if
>   you increase height you will able to see fifth tab in next row.
>
> When you reduce browser screen at max-width: 992px .tabs class

```
 .tabs {
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex
}
```

Due to display property as flex it show all tabs.This is applied by Materialize CSS.

Hope it helps you to understand some little bit.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and found out that the media queries from materialize are the reason behind the behavior you are seeing.

Currently the media queries remove the flex property for tabs at **992px**. I've simply  extended it to my screen/device width as below.

```
@media (max-width: 1900px) {

  .tabs {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

Below I've copied a working example on jsbin.

http://jsbin.com/soxadeciyo/2/edit?output

Hope this helps.